How to select values ​within a specific range in an array
Given an array let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], I need to write a function that creates a new array and puts values ​​greater than 3 and less than 6 into it. What am I doing wrong?


let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function inBetween() {
  let result = [];
  for (let num of arr) {
    if (num > 3 && num < 6) {
      result.push(num);
    }
  }
}

console.log(inBetween(arr));




You are just missing return result; before the last }

In addition to what @Godot said, Your function is not receiving argument (arr) either

To make another addition, even though this works, consider looking to the filter function. This case is perfect for it!

Does this answer your question? How to filter an array in javascript?

You can implement this function yourself, or you can just use the built-in filter method:


const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];


console.log(arr.filter(item => item > 3 && item < 6));



If you want a specific method inBetween, you'd still use filter inside of it:


const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function inBetween(arr, lowerLimit, upperLimit) {
  return arr.filter(item => item > lowerLimit && item < upperLimit);
}


console.log(inBetween(arr, 3, 6));



You can even use a functional programming approach and use a factory function that will generate exactly the function you need:


const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function inBetweenFactory(lowerLimit, upperLimit) {
  return (arr) => arr.filter(item => item > lowerLimit && item < upperLimit);
}

const between3and6 = inBetweenFactory(3,6);

console.log(between3and6(arr));




yes, I know that there are built-in method, I needed to do it using "for"
